# Запуск bat-файла на удалённом компьютере

Tags: linux, windows, http, bat, remote

Имеется 2 компьютера в одной локальной сети. Один на linux, второй на windows. На винде лежит заранее прописанный bat-файл. Как из-под линукса запустить на винде батник?

То есть нужно не чтобы батник отработал на линуксе, не чтобы команда писалась на линуксе, а исполнялась на винде. Нужно удалённо запустить батник

Единственная пришедшая мне в голову реализация - поднять простенький сервис на винде, открыть для локальной сети апишку, и с линукса по простому http стучать в эту апишку. Ощущение, что я изобрёл велосипед

Comment: ssh не подойдет?

Comment: Аркадий предложил хорошее и **проверенное** решение. Если оно не подходит, используйте средства Windows. Например, `Аудит`. С удаленного хоста (Linux) "постучитесь" по портам сервера. Создайте триггер на событие попытки доступа к портам сервера. Триггер запускает скрипт. Скрипт проверяет порядок попыток доступа к портам, При соответствии - стартует приложение (bat-файл). В приведенном примере не обязательно проверять порты. Можно воспользоваться открытыми сервисами: RDP, "Общий доступ к файлам и принтерам", "Служба времени Windows", "Обнаружение SSDP" и т.д. Гулите `port knocking`.

Comment: @Аркадий, да, спасибо, подходит